# Different language for user interface and keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

On Windows 7 I used to have the display language in English and my native language as keyboard layout. This was very easy to configure, as user interface language and keyboard layout were completely different and unrelated settings.

On Windows 10, these settings have been merged. I added English as the display language, then I configured my native language for the keyboard layout (and I also removed the English keyboard layout altogether):

[image]
[image]

However the English keyboard layout is still present as an available keyboard layout, and it is even set as the default one every time I logon:

[image]

There is a way to have different languages for the user interface and for the keyboard layout?

Comment: The keyboard layout used and the interface Windows uses is still separate.  Only thing that changed is with Windows 7 you couldn't add additional language packs without having Windows 7 Ultimate.  In both language preferences you have Italian as your chosen layout.

Comment: @Ramhound: as you can see in the posted screenshot, the keyboard layout matching the active language pack is enabled by default, even if I removed it altogether from the configuration panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Region & language settings. In Preferred languages, left-click English (United States) [or whatever is your preferred display language] and open Options. There you have the option to add other keyboard layouts and you can delete the default English layout. Coming two years late you have hopefully found a solution already, but hope this helps others!